# Copying a slide from one Google Slides presentation into another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I searched for a decent answer to this question but I couldn't come up with anything on SO so I thought I would post a new thread.

I am trying to copy a single slide from Google Slides into another using the advanced Slides service with google apps script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var originalPresentation = Slides.Presentations.get('1Lqtwb5z8NcU4VVj8OOR11AJyET70tlRRj6QIhxsEZZg');

  var slideToCopy = originalPresentation.slides[3];

  var newSlides = Slides.Presentations.create({
    title: 'New Slidedeck',
    slides: [slideToCopy]
  })
}
```

This creates the slide deck with the title, but the slide isn't copied. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create) indicates that you can pass an array of slides with the title, but nothing is copying. Does it also need the masters and layouts? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey, i'm looking exactly the same! did you find the solution for this?

Comment: No, I wish. I opened an issue with Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68126064

Comment: Not the most popular though :(

Comment: Thanks, I will help you sharing the issue with my team to star it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update at February 16, 2018

At [February 13, 2018](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/), the SlidesApp service was updated. Now, copying slides can be achieved by the native methods.

This sample script copies page 1 of `srcPresentationId` and inserts it as page 1 of the active presentation.

#### Sample script :

```
var srcPresentationId = "### source fileId ###";
var copysrcSlideIndex = 0; // 0 means page 1.

var copydstSlideIndex = 0; // 0 means page 1.

var src = SlidesApp.openById(srcPresentationId).getSlides()[copysrcSlideIndex];
SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().insertSlide(copydstSlideIndex, src);
```

#### Reference :

- [insertSlide(insertionIndex, slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#insertslideinsertionindex-slide)

### Original Answer

Do you still look for the method for copying slides? Unfortunately, I confirmed that copying using the Slides API cannot be done yet. But I thought of a workaround.

How about the following workaround? In a recent Google update, I noticed that [Class SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app) was added. I used this. Since I didn't find the method for copying a slide directly to a new presentation, I used the following flow.

#### Flow :

1. Copy the presentation using `DriveApp`.
2. Open the copied presentation.
3. Remove slides except for a slide you want to copy using [`remove()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#remove).

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var srcSlides = 3; // A page number of slide that you want to copy. In this case, the top number is 1.

  var srcid = "1Lqtwb5z8NcU4VVj8OOR11AJyET70tlRRj6QIhxsEZZg";
  var dstid = DriveApp.getFileById(srcid).makeCopy().getId();
  var dstSlides = SlidesApp.openById(dstid).getSlides();
  dstSlides.splice(srcSlides - 1, 1);
  for (var i in dstSlides) {
    dstSlides[i].remove();
  }
}
```

#### References :

- Class SlidesApp : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app
- remove() : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#remove

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I am going to mark this correct even though not the exact solution I was looking for. If you don't mind, star the feature request and hopefully they will add a method to make this possible. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68126064

Comment: @Jordan Rhea Thank you for quick reply. I also want the simple way like your script using Slides API. Now I checked the star. I want to use this workaround until the issue is solved.

Comment: @Jordan Rhea Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan Rhea I noticed that my added script copies only one element. So I modified it. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Jordan Rhea I found a more simple method for copying slides. So I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: years later still no copy possible. I'm still really waiting for this as well, anybody found another solution ?

I need to copy a slide in an existing presentation, not create a new one (I already use the copy_file from Google Drive api method, then remove slides, but that doesn't allow me to insert a slide into an already existing presentation :()

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for this ?

```
  var PresentationTEST = SlidesApp.openById(TEMPLATE_TEST);
  var PresentationTemplate = SlidesApp.openById(TEMPLATE_DEV);
  var slides = PresentationTemplate.getSlides();

  var slide = slides[0];
  var slide = PresentationTEST.appendSlide(slide);
```

Comment: Tested this solution, works like a charm. Too bad we have to move to App Scripts and can't do it in the API, but at least it works.

Comment: Edit a year later : performance is terrible, if you work with a lot of slides and want to do this, it ends up not working anymore.