# Google Slides API- insert slide from external slide into current pptx

Tags: google-slides-api

Is it possible to copy/insert a slide from one presentation to another using Google Slides API?

I came across this which is what I want but I'm not sure if 'Google Apps Script' is the same thing as Google Slides API?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#insertslideinsertionindex-slide

Apologies but I'm new to Google dev.

Comment: [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/) is different from [Slide service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/). Unfortunately, in the current stage, a slide in Google Slides cannot be directly copied to other Google Slides using Slides API. So as a workaround, how about creating an API using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with Slides service? In this case, Web Apps is created by Google Apps Script, and Web Apps can be used from outside like an API. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and for the workaround :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you have any questions for my comment, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike comment is not correct though: you can copy slides from another presentation with this snippet      ```var srcPresentationId = "aPresentationId";
 
 var src = SlidesApp.openById(srcPresentationId).getSlides()
 
 src.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
  SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().appendSlide(ele, idx)
 })```

Comment: @Davide Arcinotti OP's question is to copy the slides using Google Slides API. In the current stage, this cannot be still achieved. So I had proposed to use Google Apps Script. Because when Google Apps Script is used, OP's goal can be achieved. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47257210) In your comment, the Google Slides service is used. This is not Slides API. Unfortunately, I would like to not agree with your `@Tanaike comment is not correct though`. But, the situation that I cannot propose the solution using Slides API for achieving OP's goal is my poor skill. I have to apologize for this.